# Eat bread before drink beer make you drunk less?

Tags: drinking, alcohol-level, non-alcoholic, preparation-for-drinking, alcohol

My friends says if you eat some bread it will absorb the alcohol and make you high less. is it true?

Comment: Hi!  This question is a bit rough around the edges, we could use a bit more for discussion here.  Are you looking for advice on how to avoid a hangover, or how to avoid being too drunk?  If so, rephrase the question for one of the more open-ended variations.

Comment: When I was about 15, I downed half a bottle of alcohol and then ate a loaf of bread and never got drunk. I told someone a few weeks ago and they said I was no way because eating bread to get sober was a myth. I'm seriously confused now? Wondering if I did get drunk but dont remember. But I remember I was with friends who questioned why I wasn't drunk after cheering me on to down the bottle; so I doubt it. People can be so weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your liver processes alcohol at a fixed rate (what that rate is depends on your tolerance, current liver function, what medications you are taking, and some genetics). So eating some food, particularly foods that absorb fluids like bread, will slow down the rate of alcohol absorption into your bloodstream, allowing your liver more time to metabolize the alcohol.

So for a fixed amount of alcohol, drinking on a full stomach will make you FEEL less drunk because you spread out the alcohol absorption over time so your liver has more time to metabolize it.

However, you can still saturate your livers ability to metabolize alcohol by ingesting high volumes of alcohol and the absorptive ability of the food in your stomach is limited (unless you vomit it out) so it is FAR from reliable technique to drink but avoid becoming intoxicated or hungover since you are still absorbing all the ingested alcohol, just over a slightly longer period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Eating will absorb some of the alcohol. Drinking on an empty stomach means the alcohol can go directly to the blood stream and the effects of the alcohol will happen faster.

So if you have food in you, especially breads, it will rather slow the process of getting drunk.

Of course you could eat four loaves of bread a slam a bottle of liquor in less then a minute and it won't help you there.

Comment: nice answer, so the conclusion is nothing can stop you to get drunk? lol